# How to recreate Excel's "Index(,,Match())" function in SPSS?

Tags: excel, indexing, match, spss

I am trying to recreate Excel's "Index(,,Match())" function in SPSS. My data is organized as follows:

[image]

The "Position" variables indicate what column (T:V) the value in the "Value" variables should go.

In the 1st row, the positions are in order 1-3, so the values in columns T:V are in the same order as the "Value" variables.

In the second row the positions are 2,3,1; so the value in "Value1" should go in column U (the second column in that last block of variables), the value in "Value2" should go in the column V, and the value in "Value 3 should go in column T. And so on.

After looking into doing this in SPSS, SPSS' Index and Match functions will not help.

Do any Excel/SPSS users know how to accomplish this in SPSS with syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are probably several ways to approach the problem, depending on how many columns you're dealing with and whether they're all numeric or if there are strings (there's probably a matrix algebra answer, I just can't think of it).

If you only have 3 sets of 3 columns, the simplest approach would be to write 9 (3*3) if-statements (you don't have column names for cols T/U/V, so I'm just referencing their Excel column):

```
if (Position1 = 1) T = Value1.
if (Position1 = 2) T = Value2.
if (Position1 = 3) T = Value3.
if (Position2 = 1) U = Value1.
if (Position2 = 2) U = Value2.
...
```

This should work. If you have many more columns, you can also use vector loops to define the sets of variables.

Comment: Thanks @bwarner. Solved it with vector loops.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a scalable approach:

```
vector match(3).
do repeat p = position1 to position3 / v= value1 to value3 / y = #y1 to #y3.
compute y = v*p.
end repeat.
loop #i = 1 to 3.
compute match(#i) = any(#i, #y1 to #y3).
end loop.
exe.
```

Comment: Thanks @Jay! It works well when the value variables are binary (0,1), but fails with other values, since any returns a 0 or 1. How could the code be altered to return any value in the value variables?

Comment: An alternative approach would be to restructure using `varstocases` sort the data by position then restructure it back with `casestovars`.